# Два слеша в пути до файла Python

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, ос

обращаюсь с проблемой, а именно у меня есть бот(telegram), который должен присылать файл по путю, который я ему пришлю, так вот при получении пути она помещается в функцию open(). Но в итоге получается то, что вместо введённого пути, у меня получается путь с двумя слешами: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Знаю про r-строку, но проблема в том, что путь содержится в переменной к которой r-строка не работает. Через replace() тоже не работает т.как "" - спец символ. Есть ли какие ещё способы открытия файла, думал чтобы совместить f-строку и r-строку, но как нигде не написано.
Код: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Знаю, что уже был такой вопрос но он мне не помог(

Comment: Все правильно, путь и должен быть с двумя слешами, ну или r-строка. Если пишет, что нет такого файла или папки, значит, нет.

Comment: А есть ли способы использовать r-строку, для переменной? Просто если вводить правильные пути, то всё равно пишет, что не найдено

Comment: ``s = r"c:\Users"`` - использование р-строки для переменной.

Comment: Кстати, в строчке, где собственно отправляется файл, ошибка. Там отправляется не то. Ну и код должен быть тестом, а не фотографией.

Comment: Это я уже увидел) Исправил). Я имею про другое, у меня есть переменная в ней путь, как мне к ней применить r-строку?

Comment: вы сейчас решаете [проблему молотка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_XY_(%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0)). Дополните вопрос информацией откуда что берется. Потому что нужно решать не проблему "как применить r-строку к переменной", а "как правильно передать путь в функцию".

Comment: То что двойные слеши у вас выводит - это так и должно быть, внутри на самом деле слеши одинарные, пытаться починить слеши не нужно. Скорее всего файла действительно нет (может имя не то, или расширение, или путь неправильный)

Comment: Двойные слеши - это отображение на экране, в самой переменной слеши правильные, одинарные. Вы решаете не ту вообще проблему.